# Rails: how to validate an object field's value before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a Redmine plugin that should check if some fields of an Issue are filled depending on values in other fields.
I've written a plugin that implements `validate` callback, but I don't know how to check field values which are going to be saved.
This is what I have so far:

```
module IssuePatch

def self.included(receiver)

  receiver.class_eval do
    unloadable

    validate :require_comment_when_risk

    protected
    def require_comment_when_risk
      risk_reduction = self.custom_value_for(3)
      if risk_reduction.nil? || risk_reduction.value == 0
        return true
      end

      comment2 = self.custom_value_for(4)
      if comment2.nil? || comment2.value.empty?
        errors.add(:comment2, "Comment2 is empty")
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

The problem here is that `self.custom_value_for()` returns the value *already written* to the DB, but not the one that *is going* to be written, so validation doesn't work. How do I check for the value that was passed from the web-form?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which method is  `custom_value_for`?

Comment: @Rodrigo, it's an Issue model method

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Redmine! But this guide can help you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about rails is that in your controller you don't have to validate anything. You are suppose to do all of this in your model. so in your model you should be doing something like

```
validates :value_that_you_care_about, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

or

```
validates :buyer_name, presence: true, :length => {:minimum => 4}
```

or

```
validates :delivery_location, presence: true
```

If any of these fail this will stop the object from being saved and if you are using rails scaffolding will actually highlight the field that is incorrect and give them and error message explaining what is wrong. You can also write your own validations such as

```
def enough_red_flowers inventory
    if inventory.total_red_flowers-self.red_flower_quantity < 0
      self.errors.add(:base, 'There are not enough Red Flowers Currently')
      return false
    end
    inventory.total_red_flowers = inventory.total_red_flowers-self.red_flower_quantity
    inventory.save
    true
  end
```

To write your own custom message just follow the example of `self.errors.add(:base, 'your message')`

You can find more validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Answer (score 3):

Better way it's create custom validator

```
class FileValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # some logic for validation
  end
end
```

then in model:

```
validates :file, file: true
```